# Directive not being rendered

Tags: angularjs-directive

I have created a directive which draws a chart based on this post: http://briantford.com/blog/angular-d3.html?utm_source=javascriptweekly. The argument to the directive specifies a dataset to retrieve. When I have multiple directives in a page only the first chart is ever executed. Looking at the network traffic only the first dataset is retrieved.

```
<chart-directive datasetId="1"/>
<chart-directive datasetId="2"/>
```

I get no errors in the browser console. Its as if the second directive is never executed.

Any ideas?

Comment: where you able to get this working?

Comment: Still curious as to if you were able to find a solution to your issue 6+ mo. later

Answer (score 0):

Change your directive markup to

```
<chart-directive datasetId="1"></chart-directive>
<chart-directive datasetId="2"></chart-directive>
```

Why? Briefly, we can't have self-closing tags on our custom element directives

### [Source](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/syntax.html#syntax-start-tag)